# Integer to string length in python?

Tags: python, string, function, hash, integer

I am trying to create a function that takes an integer (n) and returns a string with n-amount of hashes.

Ex:

if n is 5,
the string would be : #####

if n is 2
the string would be : ##

Comment: What is the issue then?

Comment: This function would be quite simple. But what is the problem you're having trying to create such a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's such a function:

```
def f(n):
    return '#' * n
```

Usage:

```
>>> f(5)
'#####'
>>> f(2)
'##'
```